# "Même si dans tes danses, d'autre dansent tes heures."

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

I've always loved the song Pour Que Tu M'aimes Encore by Céline Dion; but I've never really understood the meaning of that one sentence in the chorus:

> J'irai chercher ton cœur, si tu l'emportes ailleurs.
>
> **Même si dans tes danses, d'autres dansent tes heures.**

What does it mean? I mean if I translate it, using my (limited) knowledge, it would be: "Even in your dances, others dance your hours." But that doesn't really makes sense.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Your translation is exact. The fact is that for most people, this sentence is not understandable. Some will say that the songwriter had no other rhyme. Others that the man the singer is talking to... well, enjoys the life. I am unsure what Goldman (the songwriter) had in mind, so I will not even try to answer this, but the question is justified. It was also asked on [Yahoo](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061020105134AAjPPFS) and [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/m%C3%AAme-si-dans-tes-danses.1670458/), if you want to have a look at the answers there.

Comment: note that I wouldn't write a full stop after "ailleurs", because for me the two lines are in the same sentence.

Comment: @Chop yeah I only did that because I couldn't understand the meaning, so the translation became exact and "robotic".

Comment: @radouxju But don't you put a full stop at the end of every line in a poem?

Comment: You start each line with a capital letter, but from what I know you otherwise usually use the same punctuation as in prose. Some author (e.g. Apollinaire) even removed all punctuation marks

Comment: @radouxju Je n'ai pas connu ça, merci pour partager!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut risquer une interprétation qui bien sûr rompt la rime et est beaucoup plus verbeuse :

> D'autres que moi dansent avec toi durant les heures pendant lesquelles tu danses.

Comment: C'est assez raisonnable, merci !